# When parsing, jQuery ignores anything that isn't a table and document removes the table tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html-table

Not sure if this is a bug or a feature. When parsing html with table elements outside a table, jQuery ignores non-table elements.

```
<tr><td>table data</td></tr>
<div>div after will be ignored</div>
```

passed into `$(html)` becomes

```
<tr><td>table data</td></tr>
```

When passing the same html into plain javascript `element.innerHTML = html` becomes

```
table data
<div>div after will be ignored</div>
```

Here it is in action https://codepen.io/addbrick/pen/mprBgP

EDIT: Right after posting this I realized jQuery is removing the table elements because of the opposite behavior in the dom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with, that’s not a valid HTML.

Yes. The Jquery parser cleanup that.

If you have a close look at [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) jquery, html function uses parseHTML before it actually sets the `innerHTML`.

And the parseHTML is calling a buildFragment and removing all the spurious elements inside the string.

Below is a part of source code of buildFragment function

```
// Add nodes directly
            if ( jQuery.type( elem ) === "object" ) {
                jQuery.merge( nodes, elem.nodeType ? [ elem ] : elem );

            // Convert non-html into a text node
            } else if ( !rhtml.test( elem ) ) {
                nodes.push( context.createTextNode( elem ) );

            // Convert html into DOM nodes
            } else {
                tmp = tmp || safe.appendChild( context.createElement( "div" ) );

                // Deserialize a standard representation
                tag = ( rtagName.exec( elem ) || [ "", "" ] )[ 1 ].toLowerCase();
                wrap = wrapMap[ tag ] || wrapMap._default;

                tmp.innerHTML = wrap[ 1 ] + jQuery.htmlPrefilter( elem ) + wrap[ 2 ];

                // Descend through wrappers to the right content
                j = wrap[ 0 ];
                while ( j-- ) {
                    tmp = tmp.lastChild;
                }



// Manually add leading whitespace removed by IE
            if ( !support.leadingWhitespace && rleadingWhitespace.test( elem ) ) {
                nodes.push( context.createTextNode( rleadingWhitespace.exec( elem )[ 0 ] ) );
            }

            // Remove IE's autoinserted <tbody> from table fragments
            if ( !support.tbody ) {

                // String was a <table>, *may* have spurious <tbody>
                elem = tag === "table" && !rtbody.test( elem ) ?
                    tmp.firstChild :

                    // String was a bare <thead> or <tfoot>
                    wrap[ 1 ] === "<table>" && !rtbody.test( elem ) ?
                        tmp :
                        0;
```

Yes, that is where you actual passed string gets evaluated and creating DOM nodes.

And finally, div should not be used a a element inside a table directly. Can be wrapped inside a `td` and `tr`.

So why exactly jquery ignored it ? because that is not real and valid html. If you look close at [html specification of Table](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1), you can only have the given tags. In a table tag,

```
<!ELEMENT TABLE - -
     (CAPTION?, (COL*|COLGROUP*), THEAD?, TFOOT?, TBODY+)>
<!ATTLIST TABLE                        -- table element --
  %attrs;                              -- %coreattrs, %i18n, %events --
  summary     %Text;         #IMPLIED  -- purpose/structure for speech output--
  width       %Length;       #IMPLIED  -- table width --
  border      %Pixels;       #IMPLIED  -- controls frame width around table --
  frame       %TFrame;       #IMPLIED  -- which parts of frame to render --
  rules       %TRules;       #IMPLIED  -- rulings between rows and cols --
  cellspacing %Length;       #IMPLIED  -- spacing between cells --
  cellpadding %Length;       #IMPLIED  -- spacing within cells --
  >
```

And inside a each tag

```
<!ELEMENT THEAD    - O (TR)+           -- table header -->
<!ELEMENT TFOOT    - O (TR)+           -- table footer -->
```

As you can see, there is no div tag directly allowed.

However in case of vanilla javascript [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), no such parsing happens and browser directly interprets the string provided to dom nodes and add's them to the document.

> Removes all of element's children, parses the content string and assigns the resulting nodes as children of the element.